# Android Glide alternate cache in memory or disk

Tags: android, caching, android-glide

I´m working in an App which does have images that are used quite often, however there are others download used only once.

Does Glide have any way for deciding on the fly which images should be stored only in Disk or only in memory?

As far as I´ve seen it does the cache depends on the configuration buy I´de like to be able to say by myself which ones should be in disk and which ones no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.diskCacheStrategy()`](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/DrawableRequestBuilder.html#diskCacheStrategy(com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy)) to manually control whether and how an individual request is cached on disk and [`skipMemoryCache()`](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/DrawableRequestBuilder.html#skipMemoryCache(boolean)) to control whether an individual request is cached in memory.